# AS3 EXACT_FIT Creative Work Around?

Tags: actionscript-3, image-scaling

I want my background image to fit the screen of the device. I have tried the basic code below

```
BG.height = stage.stageHeight;
BG.width = stage.stageWidth;
```

This works however, I have to choose EXACT_FIT to get it to fill the screen on different devices. THE ISSUE IS MY OTHER CONTENT GETS STRETCHED. I am wondering if there is a creative way to stretch the background using EXACT_FIT and then load in new content and find out how much the content has been stretched and reduced it to normal height and width.

In short looking for ideas or best ways to have access to full screen of device without having to stretch my content to funny proportions.

Comment: are you setting `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;` & `stage.align  = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;`?

Comment: I am using stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT; When I use NO_SCALE then the BG goes off screen and my content that I am trying to put on screen is also off screen. Using this code to place on screen. myMC.x = stage.stageWidth - myMC.width; but with NO_SCALE they are off screen because backgroud is very large and going way off screen. My stage.stageWidth is matching up to BG size.

Comment: If you want your app to have a responsive layout (adapts to all sizes), then you'll need to code your content to use the stage bounds.  There's no lazy way to use something other than NO_SCALE and not have letterboxing or aspect distortion or clipping

Comment: Ok thanks, I was just wondering if someone found a way to do it. I am sure someone out there will come up with a creative way to do it, with updates etc.

Comment: When you say "stage Bounds" do you mean getBounds?

Comment: `stage.stageWidth` & `stage.stageHeight`

Comment: when you do: `myMC.x = stage.stageWidth - myMC.width`, assuming it's a top level display object, it will be right aligned to edge of the screen when using NO_SCALE and align TOP_LEFT no matter the size and shape of the screen.   That also assumes myMC has a registration point of 0,0 (top left corner)

Comment: stage.stageHeight did not work but this did. stage.fullScreenHeight. Not sure what the difference is but the iPhone does not like stageHeight because it sees all elements off screen and adds them to the height. Perhaps its because I had my BG on the stage hard coded and this was making the stage much larger than the phone resolution.

Comment: I don't have an iPhone handy to test with, but stageHeight is a read-only variable that child content doesn't change.  The only thing that should change stage.stageHeight is the window/app size.  Be great if someone with an iPhone can verify this.